# how to create a website that prompts the user to enter his login id and password

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a website that asks the user to enter his login ID and password. Please help me to do it.

In this instance the login ID is abcd and password is abcd1234.
I am trying this piece of code(JavaScript language).But I don't know how to stop the user from visiting the site or redirect him to another site. How do I do it in a simple way?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function login()
{
var a=prompt("Enter your user ID");
var b=prompt("Enter your password");
if(a=="abcd" && b=="abcd1234")
{
    alert("Thank you for visiting");
}
else
{
    alert("Wrong ID or password!!");
}
}
login();
</script>
<h1>Hello world!!!Welcome!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (1) You're going to want to do this in *server-side* code, not *client-side* code.  Currently any user can just read the code to know the password, so you're not protecting anything.  No security can be done in client-side code.  (2) Building a website is a subject covered by many, many tutorials online.  Stack Overflow does not seek to replace those tutorials.  We'll be happy to help when you encounter a specific problem or are stuck with a specific error.

Comment: Your title title and first paragraph do not match your question at the end **But I don't know how to stop the user from visiting the site or redirect him to another site**. Surely you don't want to STOP the user from visiting your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could redirect them, if they haven't entered the correct credentials, by simply setting the window location to something else.

```
window.location.href = 'www.google.com'
```

Or you can just close the window, by calling.

```
window.close();
```

Of course, the name and password here are stored client side, so a fairly proficient user can simply read it from the source code. If you want it to be secure you can do it on the backend, but that requires knowledge of a backend language and makes the scope of the question considerably bigger.

Comment: You mean: `window.location.href = 'www.google.com'`? _answer already edited_

Comment: Whoops, yes. Forgot location is an object.

Comment: it's ok! Just the little things haha.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I'm just a beginner in JS and HTML also so don't know very much. But to create a fully protected site should I use PHP?

Comment: PHP, Ruby, Java. All languages which can be used server-side. The language is FAIRLY unimportant when it comes to security. It's mostly about good architecture and being skilled enough in one of these languages to apply best security practices. But yes, PHP is a safe bet overall.